# NSTimer Pause / Playfile1, Pause / Playfile2

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nstimer

is there way to use NSTimer to play a number of sound files to completion in order, or how would I play 3 sound files, one after another, each starting after the previous completed.

Each file is only 2 seconds and I figured I could do something with NSTimer, but the logic is escaping me.

Anyone have any suggestions

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you look into the AV Framework rather than trying to roll your own.